# Relation One to One comes Null with Laravel

Tags: laravel, eloquent

I am using Eloquent to create the queries but I have a relation One to One and I am trying to get the data and it returns null.

My models are:

```
//Customer:

class Customer extends Model
{
   protected $table = 'customers';

   protected $primaryKey = 'rut';

   public function user() {
        return $this->hasOne(User::class, 'rut');
  }
}

//User:

class User extends Authenticatable
{
   use Notifiable;

   protected $primaryKey = 'rut';

   public function customer()
   {
      return $this->belongsTo(Customer::class, 'rut');
   }
}
```

And I am doing my query like this:

```
$customers = Customer::with('user')->paginate(10);
```

It returns data but the user data is null:

```
activity: "Particular"
address: "AV. GRECIA 690 LOC 5"
commune_id: 12
created_at: null
email: "lavanderiaom@gmail.com"
phone: null
rut: 4180753
updated_at: null
```

user: null

So I wonder how can I fix it? I mean why does it come null in user? what can the problem be?

Thanks!

Comment: A `hasOne()`/`belongsTo()` relationship allows for `null`. If you want to only load records that has a `user`, use this: `$customers = Customer::with('user')->has('user')->paginate(10)`. If that collection is empty, then there's an issue with your relationship definition.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You Make the relation one to one in the wrong way:

Customer belongs to a User Not the opposite ..

```
class User extends Authenticatable
{
   use Notifiable;

   protected $primaryKey = 'rut';

   public function customer()
   {
      return $this->hasOne(Customer::class, 'customers.rut','users.rut');
   }
}

class Customer extends Model
{
   protected $table = 'customers';

   protected $primaryKey = 'rut';

   public function user() {
        return $this->belongsTo(User::class, 'customers.rut','users.rut');
  }
}
```